# PyCharm Trailing slashes on packages

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a local package repository hosted on our own servers. The packages are updated and maintained by us and we have recently installed PyCharm IDE.
[image: Python package list]

The issue I am facing is that the repository is displaying the packages with a trailing slash so I get the following error when trying to install the package

[image: Python package error]

The pip install command that is being produce is:

`pip install --index-url http://myserver.blah/python/ numpy/`

Which I think should be without the trailing forward slash on "numpy" but I am not sure if there is a flag or setting I can change to make this amendment. I've removed the server URL from the command.

Comment: Are you using the correct env ?

Comment: Very new to Python (much more comfortable in PHP), so I am using venv and my Python version is 3.7 which I think is fine?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the local repository server configurations. Check for the configuration of the server.

Comment: I think this is a possibility, but I am unsure what needs to be set in the server configurations (.htaccess perhaps needs some rewrite rule).